CORS Error on Angular only with Basic Auth
I have an Angular app that makes an httpClient.get() call to an Api.
I developed that api with SpringBoot and it should return a json.
I set @CrossOrigins(*) on each method and when I try to call the version of the Api deployed on the Weblogic server I use for testing, it works.
Anyway, now the same Api is deployed on another Weblogic Server that requires Basic Authentication.
If I try to call the Api deployed on the new Server, setting it up with the basic auth header, it gives me this two errors, like it makes two different calls

When I don't put any auth headers, it obviously returns only a 401 Authentication Failed.
So I don't think it depends from the authentication header.
Anyway, to be sure of it, I tried to make the same call from another SpringBoot app, setting it up with the same authentication header, and the it returns the json correctly.
I really don't have any clues.
Anyway this is how I set up the calls through auth interceptor:
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if(environment.authentication){
req = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept'       : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(environment.user+ ':'+ environment.password)}`,
  },
});  } 
else req = req;
return next.handle(req);}

I checked the first request (the one with 500) and the btoa header is identical to the one sent from java or from the browser.
Please suggest me what can it be...

Can you check the server logs for the error message related to the 500 error? With CORS, when sending a fetch/XHR request to another server, the client will perform an OPTIONS request to the resource in order to check for CORS errors up front. This is also called a preflight request. It might be that you need to configure your server for handling OPTIONS requests.

also remember that when sending credentialed requests you cannot set a wildcard origin.  (list the allowed domains explicitly...)  This wouldn't cause a 500 error, though, so that sounds like a bigger issue on the backend.  You should double-check verb settings and permissions as you might be vulnerable to verb tampering.

@JSONDerulo the fact is that I don't get any errors...
When I use the same backend without authentication activated, it works.
When I use it with authentication activated, it looks like it sends this other options request that gives 500.
How do I configure my java project to generally handle any OPTIONS request?
And why if I make the same request, with authentication header, from Postman, browser or from a different java application it works?

The error it's probably in your back-end, make sure that you are "disabling" the CORS
    @EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override 
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
    }
}

If this do not work, share your java code.

Thanks, in case, where do I need to put this code?
Cause at the moment I allowed cors through CrossOrigin annotation...

CORS is what relaxes the restrictions that the OP is experiencing. "Disabling CORS" is the opposite of what the OP wants to do.

Put this method in your configuration class with the @Configuration
